# Armature symmetrize wrong position

Tags: armature

I have a problem with my armature. if I symmetrize the other side of the armature is outside the model. 
[image]

If I drag it inside the model and do weigth painting the side I draged is all wrong and deformed. what am I doing wrong?

Here's the beld file

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symmetrize will use the armature's origin as the axis center, to fix your problem you could for example align the armature's origin to the dog's origin:

- Make sure that dog's origin is centered to its geometry (*Object > Set Origin > Origin To Geometry*).
- Select the dog object.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor To Selected*.
- Select the armature object.
- *Object > Set Origin > Origin To 3D Cursor*.
- Go in *Edit* mode, symmetrize again.

[image]

Comment: It now copied correctly only if I weigth paint the left side of the dog looks like it was hit by a bus. and i cant seem to manuall paint it. the right side is okay

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Its in the post now

Comment: In the IK constraint, you juste need to rotate the pole angle so that the legs do not twist

Comment: thnx that fixed it. only 1 side needed to be rotated :D